# SQL - Return a title with the highest number

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return from my database the title with the most eps.
With the following code I do get all the titles back.

```
SELECT titel, MAX(aantalafleveringen) FROM imdb.tvserie GROUP BY titel;
```

Hope that somebody can explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Many, many answers to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the maximum of *maximum per groups*, you just really want the global maximum.

This is equivalent with the other answers, but much more simple:

```
SELECT   titel, aantalafleveringen
FROM     imdb.tvserie
ORDER BY aantalafleveringen DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 1):

smth like his:

```
SELECT distinct titel, MAX(aantalafleveringen) over (partition by titel) 
FROM imdb.tvserie
ORDER BY max desc
LIMIT 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, can u explain me what the partition by titel means?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html `partition by` is "window analog" of `group by`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Order by` and `Limit`

```
SELECT titel,
       Max(aantalafleveringen) AS max_aantalafleveringen
FROM   imdb.tvserie
GROUP  BY titel
ORDER  BY max_aantalafleveringen DESC -- orders the result in descending order
LIMIT 1 -- filters the first record
```

Comment: thanks , this worked also and is better to understand for me